# a simplified signature in functools.partial

Tags: python

In the official docs to explain `functools`
[10.2. functools — Higher-order functions and operations on callable objects — Python 3.7.0 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html)

> The partial() is used for partial function application which “freezes” some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a new object with **a simplified signature**. For example, partial() can be used to create a callable that behaves like the int() function where the base argument defaults to two:

I could understand most of the statement and admit the "freeze" is a delicate and accurate word to describe the context.

What I cannot follow is "a simplified signature",
What kind of signature it refers for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature means how the function is called, if you have a function that needs five strings its signature is

```
foo (st1, st2, st3, st4, st5)
```

If you now use partial to freeze three of them, it only needs two

```
foo (st1, st2)
```

Which is "simplified" because it needs less parameters.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Impressive that you have the less reputation but have same insight with the above two master. ty.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, *simplified* just means fewer arguments. If you have

```
import functools

def func(a, b, x=8, y=9):
    print((a, b, x, y))

simple_func = functools.partial(func, 1, x=2)
```

, then `simple_func` ends up a function with one argument `a` and one keyword argument `y`:

```
>>> simple_func(3, y=4)
(1, 3, 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

A *function signature* is the name of the function, its parameters and, strictly speaking, its return type:

```
mymodule.myfunction(foo, bar=None, *, baz=42)
```

This is the *signature*. When you `partial`ly bind a function, it returns a new function, typically with fewer parameters because you have already bound a few arguments:

```
partial(mymodule.myfunction, bar='Mike')
```

The signature of this newly partially bound function is:

```
func(foo, *, baz=42)
```

A *simpler* signature than the original one.